# Exclude result from regex

Tags: regex

How can I exclude alpha characters from the end of each group of following regex:

```
\b([0-9]{1,2}\w)?([0-9]{1,2}\w)?([0-9]{1,2}\w)?([0-9]{1,2}\w)\b
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show example of input text and expected result, please? For example, I suggest replace `([0-9]{1,2}\w)` by `([0-9]{1,2}[_0-9])`

Comment: Well, I want to capture day and time from this 23d14h15m30s for example (e.g. DDdHHhMMmSSs where d = day, h = hour, m = minute, s = second)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use optional non-capturing groups, and move your captured groups into them:

```
\b(?:([0-9]{1,2})\w)?(?:([0-9]{1,2})\w)?(?:([0-9]{1,2})\w)?(?:([0-9]{1,2})\w)\b
     \__________/       \__________/       \__________/       \__________/
          1                   2                 3                  4
```

- `(...)` - Groups will be captures, just as they are now.
- `(?:...)` - Non-capturing groups. Used to group the digits and the alpha-numeric so they are all optional together: `(?:...)?`

Keep in mind that `\w` also include digits and underscores, so you may have unexpected results.

Comment: \w can be easy replaced by what do i need, so there is no problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude alphas like this:

```
[^a-zA-Z]
```

`^` means "not".